# Change Background Color of Task Row Based on Percent Complete Value

Tags: vba, conditional-formatting, ms-project

I want to change the background color of the entire task row based on the percent complete value in Microsoft Project.

The code goes through the **entire** document and changes every line to be shaded in red.

How do I get the colors to change based on the percent complete?
How do I get the code to stop running after the last line with task information?

```vb
Sub Test2()

Dim t As Task
Dim i As Integer

i = 1
For Each t In ActiveProject.Tasks

    SelectRow Row:=i, rowrelative:=False

    Select Case t.PercentComplete
        Case 100
           Font32Ex CellColor:=vbGreen
        Case 2 - 99
           Font32Ex CellColor:=vbYellow
        Case Else
           Font32Ex CellColor:=vbRed
    End Select

    i = i + 1
Next t
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Sub colorrows()
FilterEdit Name:="test", TaskFilter:=True, Create:=True, OverwriteExisting:=True, _
    FieldName:="% Complete", Test:="equals", Value:=100
FilterApply Name:="test"
SelectAll
FontEx cellcolor:=pjGreen
FilterEdit Name:="test", TaskFilter:=True, Create:=True, OverwriteExisting:=True, _
    FieldName:="% Complete", Test:="is greater than or equal to", Value:="2", ShowInMenu:=True
FilterEdit Name:="test", TaskFilter:=True, NewFieldName:="% Complete", Test:="is less than or equal to", _
    Value:="99", Operation:="And"
FilterApply Name:="test"
SelectAll
FontEx cellcolor:=pjYellow
FilterEdit Name:="test", TaskFilter:=True, Create:=True, OverwriteExisting:=True, _
    FieldName:="% Complete", Test:="equals", Value:=0
FilterApply Name:="test"
SelectAll
FontEx cellcolor:=pjRed
FilterClear

End Sub
```